# Grafana can't sent to localhost. SSL_accept error from localhost[127.0.0.1]: -1

Tags: postfix

Grafana running on the same server as postfix tries to send to it, but I get this error:

> ```
> Feb 21 08:14:00 postfix/smtpd[10624]: SSL_accept error from localhost[127.0.0.1]: -1
> Feb 21 08:14:00 ovh postfix/smtpd[10624]: warning: TLS library problem:
>     error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:
>     ../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 42:
> Feb 21 08:14:00 postfix/smtpd[10624]: lost connection after STARTTLS 
>     from localhost[127.0.0.1]
> Feb 21 08:14:00 postfix/smtpd[10624]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] 
>     ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
> ```

Can I set postfix to just accept mail from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in grafana.ini

```
[smtp]
enabled =true
;host = localhost:25
;user =
;password =
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true  <--- Setting this to true made the mail come through.
```